# Defining a circle as a limit

Tags: geometry, limits

Could I define a circle as a polygon where the amount of sides approaches infinity? How would I define this mathematically?

Comment: Can you clarify what the purpose of this definition is going to be?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it. For measuring area, it's fine, but for things like measuring length, you have to be careful to avoid situations like considering a triangle as a stack of rectangles: this suggests the length of the hypotenuse is $a+b$, not $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: No, you can't define a circle as a polygon (regardless of whatever you may write after that). For some purposes, you may define a circle as the *limit* of a *sequence* of polygons.

Comment: I wouldn't define it like that; it would be a terrible definition to work with! But you can show that the set of $n$th roots of unity, a prototypical regular $n$-gon, approaches the complex unit circle as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @pjs36: In order for your statement to be true or false, you would have to define what "a regular $n$-gon approaches the complex unit circle as $n\to \infty$" means.

Comment: @JonasMeyer That's very true; I would. Let's go with: "There's a radial bijection between the complex unit circle and points on the regular $n$-gon defined above. Call this family of bijections $\phi_n$. Then, for each point $z$ on the unit circle, the sequence $\{\phi_n^{-1}(z): n\geq 3\}$ converges to $z$ as $n \to \infty$."

Comment: @pjs36: So, pointwise convergence of a sequence of functions on $S^1$ to the identity function.  This definition would leave out a lot of nice structure, e.g., the convergence of arclength and area which would hold for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could define the circle as the limit case of a sequence of *regular* polygons as you increase the number of edges. So in a certain sense, the circle is a regular “infinitogon”.

Mathematically you could e.g. compute the ratio between the circumcircle and the incircle of a regular $n$-gon. Then you take the limit $n\to\infty$ of that ratio and observe that it converges to $1$. So in the limit, circumcircle and incircle become the same. And since any regular $n$-gon is contained in the annulus between circumcircle and incircle, in the limit the $n$-gons have to converge to a circle.